# Error in FDT when running ANT script: fdt.launch.Application supports only projects of type 'AIR All' or 'Web'

Tags: mobile, ant, air, adobe, fdt

FDT is giving the following error message when trying to run an ANT script:

BUILD FAILED: fdt.launch.Application supports only projects of type 'AIR All' or 'Web'

Why? My project is an "AIR Mobile" project. It should work, shouldn't it?

The ANT code is as simple as it gets:

```
<project name="Compile" default="compile" basedir="../">
    <target name="compile">
        <fdt.launch.application projectname="Project" mainclass="src/project/core/Main.as" target="bin/app.swf" />
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your project type is "AIR Mobile" try using **swflauncher="AIR Debug Launcher"** as a argument for launching application Eg:-

```
<fdt.launch.application projectname="Project" mainclass="src/project/core/Main.as" target="bin/app.swf" swflauncher="AIR Debug Launcher"/>
```

If your project is a simple flash based swf then change the project type to "AIR All" or "Web".

Otherwise launch the application based on launch config in settings folder.

```
<project name="Features" default="echo.project.properties">
 <target name="fdt.invoke.launchConfiguration">
   <fdt.invoke.launchConfiguration file=".settings/launch/AntTask.launch" mode="debug" />
 </target>
</project>
```

Refer :- http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Ant_Tasks

Hope this may help you..